Vendor Name in Permalinks
I use dokan in Wordpress. And I want to put the name of the seller in my permalinks.
If I do it in the form of /p/%author%, the products of two different stores with the same product overlap and numbers like -2,-3 come at the end.
function wpse_post_type_link( $permalink, $post ) {
    if ( 'product' === $post->post_type && false !== strpos( $permalink, '%author%' ) ) {
        $author = get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename', $post->post_author );
        $permalink = str_replace( '%author%', $author, $permalink );
    } else {
        $permalink = str_replace('%author%', 'p', $permalink);
    }

    return $permalink;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse_post_type_link', 20, 2 );```


